# Obtaining a negative value in unsigned int var

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Compiling these lines using VS2010

```
unsigned final_value;
long    int offset=109572;
long    lSize=2;                            //2 Bytes
char    *buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
mybinfile = fopen("binfile.bin","rb");
fseek(mybinfile,offset,SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer,lSize,1,mybinfile);
fclose(mybinfile);
sscanf(buffer,"%u",&final_value);
```

running this code, final_value returns a negative value. 
(The same code compiled using NMAKE from console returns correct positive value.) 
How can I solve this?
It can be due to one overflow 
It can be due to incorrectly setup of my vs2010

thank in advance

Comment: How do you check the `final_value` to be positive or negative?

Comment: What two bytes are at that offset in binfile and what is the expected result?

Comment: this code compiled using VS2010 c++ returns negative

Comment: the espected result, is a value coded on 2 bytes, this code works perfectly when It's compiled using NMAKE command in the console

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is used to read TEXT (strings), you are fetching two bytes and passing that to `scanf()` - unless your two bytes are precisely two digits (0x30-0x39 in values), and the next byte after that is a zero, it will definitely not do what you expect.

It is not clear exactly what you want your two bytes to represent, but I'm pretty sure what you are doing is "wrong".

As to the value being negative, how are you printing it?

Comment: the negative value appear like a wrong value in the display. I also tried  fread(&final_value,lSize,1,mybinfile); and gives the same value than the first

Comment: You probably should post the code that you are using to display "final_value" as well as the code reading it. It's hard to determine from what you have posted what is going wrong (except that you are certainly going wrong with scanf).

Comment: Remember these lines compiled using NMAKE command works perfectly. I don't know if my VS2010 is not correctly setup.

Comment: Really? Are you sure it's not something like "your value is not initialized, and just happens to be right" in the case of NMAKE, and since VS produces code to initialize uninitialized variables with something like 0xcccccccc (which is indeed negative if displayed as a signed number), it shows up as being different. Still, if you post some COMPLETE code, it's much easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: Compiling these lines using NMAKE the final_value var takes positive and real values. When I used VS2010 the code was compiled ok, but the final_value var took negative values. For this reason I imagined  my VS is not properly setup. Is it possible?

Comment: I doubt it is a configuration/setup issue. You still haven't posted how you display `final_value`. And the `scanf()` in your code is DEFINITELY wrong - there is absolutely no way that this will give you the correct value, whatever compiler or build process you are using - it's possible that you get a different value than if you use VS, but that's just "undefined behaviour", as I expect `scanf` actually does NOTHING. Edit the original post to show your current code.

Comment: The problem was solved, initializing "final_value=0" in the declaration. After that and compiled using my VS2010. I ran the code and worked perfectly giving a real value.

Comment: I introduced another change like: 
fread(&final_value,lSize,1,mybinfile); 
insted of sscanf
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Of course, that is undefined behaviour [to read a byte into a larger data type], and ONLY works by fluke (and only on processors that have the lowest byte at the lowest address - in other words "Little endian" machines).